# Parse and display JSON from REST using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, rest

I am trying to get JSON data from REST displaying on a web page using javascript
I have the following REST call working fine to the firefox console

```
function gethosts() {
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open("GET", "https://10.10.10.10/api/machine", false);
   xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
   xhttp.send();
   var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
}
```

The JSON data is the following,

```
{
  "offset": 0,
    "hosts": [
     {
       "id": "422022c0-4ca7-66a2-bf73-9b56a65c9d2f",
       "name": "System Z",
       "type": "ORIGINAL",
       "model": "System X",
       "version": "Release 01",
       "management_ip": "10.10.10.11",
       "state": "ALIVE",
       "date": "2017-01-05T17:55:58Z"
},
```

I want this displayed using html

```
Name:    System Z
Model:   System X
Version: Release 01
MGMT IP: 10.10.10.11
State:   ALIVE
```

I tried adding this to the function but it doesn't seem to work

```
obj.hosts[0].name// return name
obj.hosts[0].model // return model
$( "body" ).append("<div>"+obj.hosts[0].name+"</div>")
$( "body" ).append("<div>"+obj.hosts[0].model+"</div>")
```

The sample HTML code is,

```
    <button type="button" onclick="gethosts()">Get all Hosts</button>   
    <div id="gethosts">Hosts: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did `obj` come from? `response` is the parsed JSON.

```
function gethosts() {
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open("GET", "https://10.10.10.10/api/machine", false);
   xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
   xhttp.send();
   var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
   $("body").append("<div>"+response.hosts[0].name+"</div>")
   $("body").append("<div>"+response.hosts[0].model+"</div>")
}
```

Also, why the mix of vanilla JS and jQuery?  Why not use `$.ajax` if you already have jQuery loaded?